# Define tab size in Word document

Tags: ms-word, openxml, docx, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I would like to calculate **tab size in white spaces**, that is, *roughly* how many spaces the tab contains.

[image]

Here is a snippet of this Open XML document:

```
  <w:body>
    <w:p w14:paraId="606C743E" w14:textId="78B4DBA2" w:rsidR="009322DC" w:rsidRPr="00641B97" w:rsidRDefault="00641B97" w:rsidP="00641B97">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="KNotice"/>
        <w:keepNext/>
        <w:spacing w:after="0"/>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:tab/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r w:rsidR="00B846CC">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Some text.</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="009322DC" w:rsidRPr="00641B97">
      <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
      <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
      <w:cols w:space="720"/>
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
```

I will use Open XML SDK for parsing, but before, trying to find property responsible for this tab size, for example, changing `<w:szCs w:val="20"/>` does not affect.

I noticed that this size is changed while manipulating First Line Indent or Left Indent, hence I assume there is not some *single* property that stores value of tab size and maybe I have to manipulate some several properties for that.

Is there such property in document structure? Or it should be calculated in some way?

Comment: The number of white spaces depends on the font being used for the white space. Both the typeface and size matter. Tabs are defined in distance, not characters, unlike a typewriter. Tabs and Indents are stored in paragraph formatting (best in styles) and can be different in every paragraph.

Comment: Calculating tab size is not that simple... In this particular case, the tab size is equal to that paragraph's special indentation (hanging) minus left indentation. Those values are probably defined in that referenced style (the "KNotice" paragraph style). However, note that if there was a tab stop element defined between then the tab size would be the tab stop location minus the left indentation. However, if the tab stop type is "right" or "center" then the size will also depend on the text that is located after the tab.